# Reading/writing a BINARY File with Strings?

Tags: java, string, binary, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

How can I write/read a string from a binary file?

I've tried using `writeUTF` / `readUTF` (DataOutputStream/DataInputStream) but it was too much of a hassle.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Java 7 take a look at the new [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class.

Comment: Makes me envious, but Java 7 gives me incompatibilities with many older programs, I'd rather do it another way.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and where you are getting errors/problems.

Comment: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 17 when using readUTF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about FileWriter, DataOutputStream for a moment.

- For binary data one uses `OutputStream` and `InputStream` classes. They handle `byte[]`.
- For text data one uses `Reader` and `Writer` classes. They handle `String` which can store all kind of text, as it internally uses Unicode.

The crossover from text to binary data can be done by specifying the encoding, which defaults to the OS encoding.

- `new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, encoding)`
- `string.getBytes(encoding)`

So if you want to avoid `byte[]` and use String you must abuse an encoding which covers all 256 byte values in any order. So no "UTF-8", but maybe "windows-1252" (also named "Cp1252").

But internally there is a conversion, and in very rare cases problems might happen. For instance `é` can in Unicode be one code, or two, `e` + combining diacritical mark right-accent `'`. There exists a conversion function (java.text.Normalizer) for that.

One case where this already led to problems is file names in different operating systems; MacOS has another Unicode normalisation than Windows, and hence in version control system need special attention.

So on principle it is better to use the more cumbersome byte arrays, or ByteArrayInputStream, or java.nio buffers. Mind also that String `char`s are 16 bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write text you can use Writers and Readers.

You can use Data*Stream writeUTF/readUTF, but the strings have to be less than 64K characters long.

---

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    // generate a million random words.
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        words.add(Long.toHexString(System.nanoTime()));

    writeStrings("words", words);
    List<String> words2 = readWords("words");
    System.out.println("Words are the same is " + words.equals(words2));
}

public static List<String> readWords(String filename) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
    int count = dis.readInt();
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(count);
    while (words.size() < count)
        words.add(dis.readUTF());
    return words;
}

public static void writeStrings(String filename, List<String> words) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename)));
    dos.writeInt(words.size());
    for (String word : words)
        dos.writeUTF(word);
    dos.close();
}
```

prints

```
Words are the same is true
```

Comment: I am already using writeUTF/readUTF - it is too much of a hassle. Did I mention that I wanted to read/write from a binary file not plain text? Sorry... edited main post

Comment: I can't imagine anything simpler than using writeUTF/readUTF.  Without seeing you code I can't imagine what is cause you hassle.